# Node.JS, MongoDB TypeError: undefined function

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have an error on a function call but I don't really know why it doesn't works.

```
.get(function(req, res) {
        Appointment.find({'creator._id':'55836c3929294c2506000001'}).toArray(function(err, appoint){
            console.log("retrieved records:");
            console.log(appointment);
        });
    });
```

Here you can find my error alert :

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Object.handle (/Users/maximesauvage/Appoint/server.js:199:67)
```

(It's my find method on the row 199)

I just want to get the "Appointment" rows where creator._id = 55836c3929294c2506000001

My Appointment JSON structure (an example):

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "55846bd717ed43180f000002"
},
"creator": {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "55836c3929294c2506000001"
    },
    "username": "hello",
    "email": "hello@toto.com",
    "__v": 2
```

Comment: where does "appointment" come from?

Answer (score 0):

```
.get(function(req, res) {
        Appointment.find({'creator._id':'55836c3929294c2506000001'}, function(err, appoint){
            console.log("retrieved records:");
            var appointment = $.map(appoint, function(arr) { return arr; });
            console.log(appoint);
        });
    });
```

.toArray is a jQuery function and can be used only on jQuery objects. Try the above code.